# sp_executesql returns a sql query with string fields for non-string in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to execute Stored Procedure by creating in SQL Server 17.0 first and pulling it into Entity Framework 6.0 for Unit Test purpose using Microsoft Unit Testing Framework

Below is the Stored Procedure I created in the Backend.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetInteger]
    (
        @name VARCHAR(255)
    )
    AS
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @parameters NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET FMTONLY OFF

    SET @Sql = 'SELECT ID, AGE, DOB FROM DETAILS WHERE NAME = @name'

    set @parameters='@name VARCHAR(255) = NULL'

    IF @Sql <> ''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_Executesql @Sql,@parameters,@name=@name
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT '' AS ID, '' AS AGE, '' AS DOB
    END
```

In Entity Framework, after pulling the SP, it is generating a class as below

```
public partial class sp_GetInteger_Result
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string AGE { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
}
```

In Unit Test class, I am executing as below

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_GetInteger()
{
    var result = db.sp_GetInteger("John").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here the class generated in EF is having fields with string datatypes though it is `int` and `datetime` in the backend table.

Whenever I generate EF entities, I need to modify the `_Result` class and my project and I cannot go everywhere and modify the datatypes and get the result.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: *"in SQL Server 17.0"*? The latest version of SQL Server is SQL Server 2019, which is currently at version 15.0.2000.5. There is no SQL Server Version 17 (that would be something like SQL Server 2023).

Comment: The stored procedure returns `' '` for Id, Age and Dob. That's why the properties are created as string.

Comment: I  *assume* (because why wouldn't it be) that `ID`, `AGE` and `DOB` aren't `varchar` datatypes, so why in your `ELSE` are you returning empty string values? Isn't that your real problem here? (*I also hope that `AGE` is a calculated column, not stored, unless people don't age in your system.*)

Comment: You should not be using `sp_Executesql`. You can directly execute the select query. `IF @Sql <> ''` will never be false.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya what's wrong with `sp_executesql`? That's a sweeping statement and I completely disagree with it.

Comment: The SQL Server Management Studio is v17.1. I use sp_executesql to avoid SQL Injection. If I modify the `ELSE` part, will it work will it change to `int` and `datetime` like passing 0 and DateMin Value? And is `SET FMTONLY OFF` a problem here?

Comment: `sp_executesql` doesn't "avoid injection" @Ch. . Parametrisation and safe injeciton avoids injection. Here there is no reason to use a "dynamic" statement, you could just replace the line `EXEC sp_Executesql @Sql,@parameters,@name=@name` with `SELECT ID, AGE, DOB FROM DETAILS WHERE NAME = @name;` and bin the `@SQL` and related parameters; it would be complete safe from injection. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Mine is a very long procedure and was using `EXEC @SQL`. If I define parameters explicity by passing to `sp_executesql`, it will avoid SQL Injection to my knowledge as your link states. Now I am only bothered about how to dynamically pull the correct data types based on fields in the table. But, thanks for your valuable help @Larnu.

Comment: The whole point of using stored procedure and not the string concanated SQL queries is to avoid SQL injection. OP here is creating dynamic SQL statement in stored procedure which is unnecessary if the intention is to return the output of Select query. The select query can be directly run in the procedure. That's the point I wanted to convey. SQL injection is not the concern here coz it's already taken care. @Larnu

Comment: I know that, @ChetanRanpariya but your statement was simply *"You should not be using `sp_Executesql`"* not "You shouldn't be using `sp_executesql` in this scenario", therefore I read your statement as "you should never use it (`sp_executesql`)", as that's what you'd effectively written. I do agree the OP doesn't need it here, as I comment above.

Comment: That ***isn't*** what I say in the article at all @Ch. . Something like `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N' SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name = ' + @Name; EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;` is completely open to injection. There is explicitly a section in that article called *"Don’t use Dynamic SQL if your statement isn’t Dynamic"* (The first section), and that is exactly what you are doing here. There's no need for dynamic SQL. You're misunderstanding *when* you should be using `sp_executesql` for a dynamic statement. What you have is **not** dynamic.